# Как послать запрос с данными к api реализованному через fastapi?

Tags: python, api, fastapi

Разбираю документацию fastapi, там есть реализация запроса:

```
from typing import Union

from fastapi import FastAPI
from pydantic import BaseModel


class Item(BaseModel):
    name: str
    description: Union[str, None] = None
    price: float
    tax: Union[float, None] = None


app = FastAPI()


@app.post("/items/")
async def create_item(item: Item):
    return item
```

Но как послать такой запрос не из автоматом генерирующейся страницы? Пробовал через postman в body, но выдовало ошибку? Буду очень благодарен, если подскажите, как это сделать!

Answer (score 0):

Ошибка была в передаваемом формате, запрос для постмэна в json:

```
{
    "name": "Item Name",
    "description": "Item Description",
    "price": 10.99,
    "tax": 1.5
}
```

Главное, чтобы формат был указан json.